# how to compress a bmp image in unix

Tags: python, unix, bmp, xlwt

I need to insert an image into an xls using the xlwt module of python. And the xlwt module seems to support only .bmp images.

So which is the best way to compress a .bmp image in unix without much quality loss ?

Initially the image size is around 3.2 MB, I want to reduce to less than 350KB, without losing much quality.

Answer (score 2):

The bitmap file format doesn't really [support compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Compression), so without reducing resolution or colors, you won't be able to reduce the filesize.

So if you only can user bmp, I'm affraid there is no way.